# How are the ascii diagrams in RFC's generated?

Tags: networking, ascii, rfc, ascii-art

Not sure if this is the correct stackexchange to ask this question, but I was wondering whether anyone knows if the ascii diagrams in 
http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5755.txt page 6 are handcrafted or generated using a program that takes the nodes and transitions as input.

If they are generated, does anyone know which program?

Directly searches on Google do not turn up anything relevant.

Comment: They are many ASCII diagram converters online. You can draw quickly in any drawing tool for example, MsPaint an then can be converted to ASCII art.

Comment: don't know how they do it in the RFCs but try this: http://www.asciiflow.com/ Lets you draw with ASCII art, no conversion needed...

Comment: May helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68875191/680372

Comment: Similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126630/4422.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that Emacs picture-mode, table-mode (`M-x table-insert` or `M-x table-recognize`) and possibly another modes simplify ASCII editing.

Also read about proposal to use PDF formats for RFC:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ash-alt-formats-02

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer, you could also draw ASCII diagrams manually with asciiflow. I find this tool pretty handy from time to time.
http://asciiflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

In fact, ietf's documentation gives instruction about [Generating ASCII-art diagrams](https://authors.ietf.org/diagrams), for example you can use asciiflow or Textik.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35530192)